# Changing the color of title text of Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to get worked a custom settings activity and I would like to change the black default color of preferences.

[image]

Comment: [see solution with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607302/how-to-change-text-color-of-preference-category-in-android)

Comment: @shuabing not really helped, but anyway, thank you.