# How display long SwitchPreference name (Android)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

Our app has some SwitchPreferences which are difficult to describe within the ~ 20 characters to the left of the Off/On switch.

I see lots of Q&A's that discuss modifying characteristics of preferences. E.g.
[How can I change font size in PreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334828/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-preferencescreen)

The answers involve referencing a layout from the preference(s) to be altered.

What would a layout look like, to change the display of a SwitchPreference,
so that the title could use the full width of the screen?
(With the text above or below the Off/On Switch)

Or is there a different widget that would have more room for explanatory text?

Comment: Why not use the description, along with the title?

Answer (score 3):

(Thanks to CommonsWare's comment above)

For most `Preference`s, put additional detail in `android:summary`.

Ex:

```
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="your_pref_key"
        android:title="@string/your_short_pref_title"
        android:summary"=@string/long_description_that_gives_more_explanation" />
```

For a `SwitchPreference`, usually it is sufficient to describe the `On` state, with the `Off` state implicitly being the negation of that. In this case, can use `android:summary`, like any other `Preference` rather than needing `summaryOn` and `summaryOff`.

HOWEVER, If, as in my case, there is slightly different explanation desired for each of the On and Off cases of a `SwitchPreference`, then the additional description must be appended to both the On and Off summaries:

```
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="your_pref_key"
        android:title="@string/your_short_pref_title"
        android:summaryOn"=@string/summary_on_with_extra_description"
        android:summaryOff"=@string/summary_off_with_extra_description" />
```

where file `values/strings.xml` contains the mentioned strings.