# How can i change fontFamily and textSize of SwitchPreference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencescreen

How can i change those font attributes of a SwitchPreference?

I already tried to use `app:layout` attribute with the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="MY-FONT"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="MY-FONT"
        android:text="Summary" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

That doesn't work well, because the switch was missing and everything looks a bit messy.

**What is an easy (and working) way to customize the fontfamily and textSize?**

Comment: The switch is missing because when you provide a layout like that, it's your responsibility to provide a Switch, a TextView and so on. Add a 
`<Switch>` element with an id `@android:id/switch_widget`. And try to style your layout, try using `ConstraintLayout`. I personally faced the same issue and I styled the preference completely using a custom layout.

Comment: @Suleyman thanks - adding <Switch> element was the solution!

Comment: No worries! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Custom Switch Preference by extending its main class

```
public class CustomSwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference {
    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        TextView title1= (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        title1.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(),R.font.noto_sans_regular));
        TextView title2= (TextView) holder.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
        title2.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(),R.font.noto_sans_regular));
    }
}
```

and use this is in your preferences xml

from

```
<SwitchPreference 
   .....
/>
```

to

```
<com.example.myapp.CustomSwitchPreference
....
/>
```

This Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

To change the font family in android first you need to have the font in your app something like this
[Your font goes in the font directory under res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrBcs.png)

Now to use it, your going in the right way

```
 <Button
            ...

            android:fontFamily="@font/nameOfFont"
            ... />
```

Let me now if it works for you

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. I need to know how to set font for a SwitchPreference, which is part of the Preferences (PreferenceScreen). The SwitchPreference has no fontFamily attribute like a button or textview.

Comment: Hi Jan, [Stackoverflow ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334828/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-preferencescreen) in that link they were able to get what you want, i think