# How to change the font size of a preference?

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences

I don't know how to change the font size of a few preferences. I have tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334828/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-preferencescreen) but it didn't work. After doing it, my icon did not show up. 
This is what it looks like now but I think that the title of the Preference is too big.
Here is what my screen currently looks like:

[image: Image of the screen]

Here is the code for my **pref_headers.xml** xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:key="@string/key_pref_general"
        android:title="@string/label_pref_general"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"/>

        <Preference
            android:key="@string/key_pref_categories"
            android:title="@string/label_pref_categories"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"/>

        <Preference
            android:key="@string/key_pref_productivity"
            android:title="@string/label_pref_productivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_chart"/>

        <Preference
            android:key="@string/key_pref_delete"
            android:title="@string/label_pref_delete"/>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution for you.you can change font size for specific preference by managing layout file.

Here is your edited **pref_headers.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Preference
    android:key="general"
    android:title="General"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
    android:layout="@layout/font_layout"/>

<Preference
    android:key="categories"
    android:title="Categories"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_list_black_24dp"
    android:layout="@layout/font_layout"/>

<Preference
    android:key="productivity"
    android:title="Productivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_timeline_black_24dp"
    android:layout="@layout/font_layout"/>

<Preference
    android:key="delete_this_accnt"
    android:title="Delete this Account"
    android:layout="@layout/font_layout"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the layout(**font_layout.xml**) file from which you can change font size or any attribute which you want to change like color etc.:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="#201f1f"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: This works, thank you. But I want to know how this works. Why does the android:id have a /

Comment: It means that you want to change font size of title and you have specified a key "android:title" in preference file so i have taken that key as a id in text-view of font_layout so it will target the changes in the key "android:title" of preference file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can also change it in your style

```
 <!-- Custom Preference Theme inherits from the v14 support library Material Theme -->
<style name="AppPreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>

<!-- And set preference Theme in your Main Theme-->
<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppPreferenceTheme</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

```
    <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Category"
    android:textSize="20px">

    <Preference
    android:key="@string/key_pref_general"
    android:title="@string/label_pref_general"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="@string/key_pref_categories"
        android:title="@string/label_pref_categories"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="@string/key_pref_productivity"
        android:title="@string/label_pref_productivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chart"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="@string/key_pref_delete"
        android:title="@string/label_pref_delete"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: Also check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334828/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-preferencescreen

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the **icon size** in a preference screen use this method I found out after playing around a bit (inspired by @S-R answer)

Let's say you have 48dp icons which are too big for the Preferences, scale it to 36dp:

```
<style name="AppPreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
        <item name="android:layout_width">36dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">36dp</item>
</style>

<!-- And set preference Theme in your Main Theme-->
<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/AppPreferenceTheme</item>
</style>
```

For some reason, this only effects the ImageView and not the text or checkboxes or what ever in the screen. Please test before using ...