# How to make title of PreferenceScreen resizable?

Tags: android, preferencescreen

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:title="@string/game_title">
```

I've a preference screen for my app for which I've added the title. When the app gets opened in split screen and resized to different size in window, the title is disappearing when the width present is smaller.

Tried adding,

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

property to the `PreferenceScreen` but it didn't help. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334828/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-preferencescreen/16044078#5906729), you can create a custom layout for the `PreferenceScreen` and apply it with `android:layout` attribute

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout="@layout/preference_title"
                  android:title="@string/game_title">
```

preference_title.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/preference_title"/>
```

And create different versions of `res/values/dimen.xml` file to have variable value of the title text size (`@dimen/preference_title`) that are proportional to possible screen widths .. typically you'll have different versions `values` directory, for instance for a screen width of w600dp, you'll have `values-w600dp` directory.

Comment: Thank you for this answer !! It's much helpful. I'm facing this issue with split screen when during dragging the window size to custom size. Will adding values in dimen.xml help still?

Comment: @TomTaylor logically it will if you pick suitable text sizes compared to screen sizes, I couldn't try it on the emulator as it doesn't support popup-view that shrinks the layout .. let me try it tomorrow on physical device and feedback .. and thanks for your kind words! :)

Comment: @TomTaylor just tested it now and worked seamlessly .. although I couldn't see the same issue you have.. but resizing the popup view changes the text size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly ! It's due to other layouts and others stacked within `PreferenceScreen` I tried as you said with simple text view and a back button image in my case (to navigate to previous screen) with linear layout - it works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot once again !!!